# C# Variable with different amount of generic args based on some condition

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I'm not sure if the title is describing this in the best way so I'll just get to the problem- I have a variable `pabs` that will be a list of 4-tuples, 5-tuples, or 6-tuples based on some condition...the problem is I don't really know which one it will be so I'm having trouble declaring the type for this variable.

Basically I want to do this:

```
if (condition1)
    pabs = loadData() // returns a list of 4-tuples
else if (condition2)
    pabs = loadData() // overloaded version returning a list of 5-tuples
else
    pabs = loadData() // overloaded version returning a list of 6-tuples
```

Is this possible at all?

Comment: Why not make `LoadData` return a `List<T>`, instead of a tuple with a bunch of stuff inside? Or, if not all elements are of the same type `T`, then create a class that contains all that data and make `LoadData` create an instance of it.

Comment: Well what would you try to do with that data afterwards? You could declare `pabs` as type `IList` for example, or just `object`...

Comment: All the types are different in each case so I'm not sure a wrapper class will help. For now I'm going to try declaring it as an object.

Comment: What you mean exactly with a 'list of n-tuples'. The list is defined List<T>, you sould say 'a list of tuple of n elements'

Answer (score 0):

What you mean exactly with a 'list of n-tuples'? you should say a list of tuple of n elements' because .net define the list as `List<T>` and many tuples as `Tuple<T>, Tuple<T1, T2>, Tuple<T1, T2, T3>, ...`

If you want that the variable **pabs** be a `List<Tuple<T1,..., T4>>` or `List<Tuple<T1,..., T5>>` or `List<Tuple<T1,..., T6>>`. Then you want that **pabs** can take three different types. Therefore you can't give a common type for this three different types unless  ***object***.
Later for use bads you must ask for its type and depending what type it is, doing something.

```
if(pabs is List<Tuple<T1,..., T4>>){...}
else if(pabs is List<Tuple<T1,..., T5>>){...}
else{...}
```